How to add additional fields in newsletter subscription mutations in Magento2
How to add additional fields in newsletter mutation?
mutation {
  subscribeEmailToNewsletter(
    email: "email@example.com"
  ) {
    status
  }
}

I want to add firstname & lastname in the above mutation.
I extended the schema.graphql from newsletter module.
But I don't know how to update these two fields alongs with email address.
default syntax

mutation: {subscribeEmailToNewsletter(email: String!): SubscribeEmailToNewsletterOutput}

